# Ruby on Rails script installation help for site5 account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, installation

I want to install Ruby on Rails application fedena (open source school management system) on site.com account anybody have the experience or can install help me.

Further details is available here:
http://www.projectfedena.org/install

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to rent hosting from a reputable company and setup Phusion Passenger or a similar solution and then deploy Fedena onto the hosted server and get your 'site.com' DNS records updated to point to the new hosting. You could run this locally if the school was willing to find a suitable server to host it on.

I'm going to be realistic and say that there is too much to be done here by someone with no experience with Rails (especially if you're wanting to deploy on Windows). I would look into finding someone with experience to assist you through the process. It might cost you a little but it will save on time and frustration.